# Uploading a small audio file from iOS app to a Python-Flask server

Tags: ios, audio, flask, http-post, nsurlconnection

I have literally gone through each and every StackOverflow post related to audio file upload from an iOS app, but haven't been able to get my code working.

Basically, I am creating an app which can record a sound, the sound is then sent to a python-flask server, which runs some machine learning algorithms on the soundfile and returns a value to the client(iOS app). I have the recording part working, and have been ale to communicate effectively with the server BUT I am having trouble with sending the audio file to the server.

So my question is of two parts: 1. How to send the audio file from iOS to the server? 2. How to read the received audio file in the server?

Here are my codes:

```
// Code to send an audio file to a local Python-Flask server (this code has been taken from a few answers on Stack Overflow)

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:5000"]];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Audio data
NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
[postData appendData:[header dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//add your filename entry
NSString *contentDisposition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"filename", @"sound.wav"];
[postData appendData:[contentDisposition dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/talhajansari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/E1061366-05C2-4412-B381-39023F3C6C18/Documents/sound.wav"]];
NSString *endItemBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary];
[postData appendData:[endItemBoundary dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And my code for the server is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
import uuid
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
app = Flask(__name__)

# for ios
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def classify():
    soundFile = request.file
    #run the algorithm on soundFile to get a particular value specific to the sound file
    return jsonify({'answer':str(value)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

For now, the code is not working. I am either not sending the file correctly from the client side, or not reading it properly on the server side. Basically, request.file is empty.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's `request.files['filename']` you're looking for, not `request.file`. From [flask's docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/):

```
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
```